# Create multiple IP Adresses on Pi

Tags: networking, raspbian-jessie

I'm running TVheadend on my Pi 2 with Raspbian 8 Jessie. I would like to use an Sat over IP receiver with Tvheadend and to be able to receive all 4 streams of the receiver I need 4 (virtual) IP's on my Pi. 
This project is related to  [this](https://blag.nullteilerfrei.de/2017/08/07/using-a-fritzbox-6490-as-tuner-for-tvheadend/)  tutorial.

What I already did was configuring `/etc/interfaces/` and `/etc/dhcpd.conf`.
But `ifconfig` still shows only one IP Adress.

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces/`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.24
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet manual
vlan-raw-device eth0

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet manual
vlan-raw-device eth0


auto eth0:3
iface eth0:3 inet manual
vlan-raw-device eth0

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And this is my `/etc/dhcpd.conf`

```
nohook lookup-hostname
interface eth0
  static ip_address=192.168.0.24/24
  static routers=192.168.0.1
  static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1

interface eth0:1
  static ip_address=192.168.0.71/24
  static routers=192.168.0.1
  static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1

interface eth0:2
  static ip_address=192.168.0.72/24
  static routers=192.168.0.1
  static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1

interface eth0:3
  static ip_address=192.168.0.73/24
  static routers=192.168.0.1
  static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Comment: Both interfaces eth0:2 and eth0:3 have been assigned with the same IP Address of 192.168.0.72 and that could probably cause some problems.

Comment: @user91822 I corrected this mistake, but still I only get one IP Adress working.

Comment: If you are able to SSH into your device using each of the IP Addresses, then I would say your configuration would be OK.

Comment: @user91822 I tried to login via SSH using one of these IP Adresses, but none worked.

Comment: Which IP address is the one that is working?

Comment: @RubberStamp 192.168.0.24 is working

Comment: The [link](https://blag.nullteilerfrei.de/2017/08/07/using-a-fritzbox-6490-as-tuner-for-tvheadend) you provided clearly says the *sub-interfaces can not use DHCP*. So, I don't know your use of **iface eth0:1 inet manual** and NOT **iface eth0:1 inet static** will make any difference. Regardless, can you see all the IP Addresses when you execute *ifconfig* from your shell terminal?

Comment: @apfelcast You should probably accept Jaromandas answer, out of courtesy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me

First, remove the `interface eth0:?` stuff in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` - but keep the entries for `interface eth0`

second, create a file in `/etc/network/interfaces.d` - call it whatever `eth0-subs` or something, name doesn't matter

The content of that file:

```
auto eth0:1
allow-hotplug eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    vlan-raw-device eth0
    address 192.168.0.71
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1

auto eth0:2
allow-hotplug eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
    vlan-raw-device eth0
    address 192.168.0.72
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1


auto eth0:3
allow-hotplug eth0:3
iface eth0:3 inet static
    vlan-raw-device eth0
    address 192.168.0.73
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

I'm not 100% sure the `allow-hotplug` is actually needed, but I had issues when I was trying to get this working

---

NOTE: I've enabled `predictable interface names` and I found it is impossible to create such "sub-interfaces" at all

i.e. even `ifconfig enxXXXXXXXXXXXX:0 192.168.1.3` just changes the IP address of `enxXXXXXXXXXXXX` and does not "create" a sub-interface

OK - for those who use "predictable interface names"

```
auto enxb827ebXXXXXX
allow-hotplug enxb827ebXXXXXX

iface enxb827ebXXXXXX inet static
  address 192.168.0.71
  netmask 255.255.255.0

iface enxb827ebXXXXXX inet static
  address 192.168.0.72
  netmask 255.255.255.0

iface enxb827ebXXXXXX inet static
  address 192.168.0.73
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

`ifconfig` in this case will probably show `192.168.0.71` as the primary for `enxb827ebXXXXXX` - but `ip address show` will show all four addresses, with `0.24` as the last secondary - if this is an issue, then remove the `eth0` entry in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, and add

```
iface enxb827ebXXXXXX inet static
  address 192.168.0.71
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
```

just below `allow-hotplug`

Comment: Thank you! Now I got the 4 addresses working. But I need the 0.24 as my primary address. I think you tried to explain that in your post but I did not really understand what to do, because in `dhcpcd.conf` the only eth0 entry is the one with 0.24.

Comment: remove eth0 settings from dhcpcd.conf and add it as `auto eth0` etc in the file you created above - I know everything you read is saying `/etc/networks/interfaces` is "deprecated" or similar, but it seems that this is the only way to get sub-interfaces working

Comment: hang on ... that primary/secondary problem is with *predictable interface names* (I thought)

Comment: I'm not using _predictable interface names_ but it seems I do have the same issue.

Comment: hmmm, that's weird - does it being secondary according to `ip address show` matter? You could always remove the `eth0` stuff from `dhcpcd.conf` and add the entries for eth0 in the file you created for the answer I guess

Comment: With adding 0.24 to the file I now have this address as primary. Now everything works perfect! Thank you.